# Is there a "Limit Point" Analogue for an Uncountable Family of Real Functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{f_i\}$ is an uncountable family of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

If $\exists f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\forall \{f_{i_n}\} \subseteq \{f_i\}$ s.t. $f_{i_n} \ne f$ and $f_{i_n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise, is there a special name for $f$?

It seems that $f$ is acting as the functional analogue of a limit point in a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Welcome to calculus of variations. :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you take subsequences and not subnets? Is that the point of your question?

Comment: I assume this concept must be pretty basic then haha. I haven't taken topology or calculus.